# Do 辩论 and 吵架 both mean "to argue"?

Tags: meaning, difference

For some reason, I imagine the difference is quite significant, but in which two directions do these verbs (辩论 and 吵架) go? How do they differ?

Comment: see dictionaries, e.g. bkrs,  **吵架**  to quarrel
to have a row  **辩论**  argue; debate:
**吵架**  syn. 相关: 争吵, 吵, 口角, 吵嘴, 斗嘴, 拌嘴, 口舌, 扯皮, 抬杠, 抬
**辩论**  syn.同义: 争辩, 声辩, 申辩, 答辩
相关: 争论, 争辩, 争鸣, 力排众议, 反驳, 回驳, 声辩, 理论, 申辩, 答辩, 置辩, 舌战, 讲理, 论争, 论战, 论理, 说理, 辩, 辩护, 辩解, 辩驳, 驳, 驳斥,"汉语同义词词典"  only has the pair **辩论／争辩**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- 辯論 means *to debate*.
- 吵架 means *to quarrel*.

They both mean *to argue*, but 辯論 is more about presenting logical arguments in a cool, calm and collected manner in an attempt to derive a conclusion from an intellectual problem, while 吵架 is a chaotic and emotional argument with people getting upset.

Answer (score 0):

辩论=debate

a formal discussion of an issue at a public meetingor in a parliament. In a debate two or more
speakers express opposing views and then there isoften a vote on the issue.

吵架=quarrel
(with sb/betwecn A and B) (aboul/ oversth) an angry argument or disagreement betweenpeople, often about a personal matter